# Increase concurrent users by limiting container resources with docker-swarm

Tags: containers, docker-swarm

Consider the scenario where I have:

- 4 replicas of an app
- 4 cores
- On load, the app consumes 100% for a single core

Can I tell each replica to only use 50% of the core and if so, would this allow at most 8 simultaneous connections to the app? I have just dipped my toe into this stuff so an feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general: No you can't. At least not on the Docker level.

You can maybe code your app in a way that it monitors such metrics and adjusts itself but Docker isn't able to.

What Docker CAN do is limit the app to 50% and kill it if it uses more than that by utilizing resource limits:

[docs.docker.com - containers/resource_constraints](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

[docs.docker.com - docker-compose resource limits](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#resources)